# MicroK8s Metallb random error when calling a service

Tags: microk8s, metallb

I'm setting up a k8s cluster using a scaleway machine (4cpu & 8g memory) using microk8s with following add-on:

```
microk8s is running
high-availability: no
addons:
  enabled:
    dns                  # CoreDNS
    helm3                # Helm 3 - Kubernetes package manager
    registry             # Private image registry exposed on localhost:32000
    storage              # Storage class; allocates storage from host directory
    metallb              # Loadbalancer for your Kubernetes cluster
```

I used helm to deploy a nodejs express API, and I tested it using `kubectl port forward`

Now, I'm trying to use metallb to be able to access it from an nginx, so I deployed a service & then I get the following:

```
my-api-service              LoadBalancer   10.152.183.14    10.64.140.43     8080:32668/TCP   34m
```

But when I tried to access it via the service :

- With metallb addon disabled: i can access it via the clusterIp
- With metallb addon enabled: I can access it via the externalIp, but sometimes the connection is reset:

```
greg@sd-69380:~$ curl 10.152.183.15:8080/
{"statusCode":404,"error":"Not Found","message":"Not Found"} # The API return a 404, excepted behavior
greg@sd-69380:~$ curl 10.152.183.15:8080/
{"statusCode":404,"error":"Not Found","message":"Not Found"}
greg@sd-69380:~$ curl 10.152.183.15:8080/
{"statusCode":404,"error":"Not Found","message":"Not Found"}
greg@sd-69380:~$ curl 10.152.183.15:8080/
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 10.152.183.15 port 8080: Connection refused # This is the problem
{"statusCode":404,"error":"Not Found","message":"Not Found"}
greg@sd-69380:~$ curl 10.152.183.15:8080/
{"statusCode":404,"error":"Not Found","message":"Not Found"}
greg@sd-69380:~$ curl 10.152.183.15:8080/
{"statusCode":404,"error":"Not Found","message":"Not Found"}
greg@sd-69380:~$ curl 10.152.183.15:8080/
```

So, when I tried to make request using nginx, sometimes I got 502 because nginx is not able to access the API.

I've got not problem when I use port-forward, so the problem is not on the API side.

I'd appreciate any help you could give me!

Comment: Are you fixed issue?

Comment: Hi @AntonPatsev, I fixed it when I later upgrade to a newer microk8s version